How to reduce the space between chapter number and text?
I need to reduce the size of the space between chapter number and text. How could I do that? This is my MWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\normalsize\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\\thechapter}{10pt}{\large}
      
\begin{document}

\chapter*{1}

\lipsum

\end{document}


do you really have \chapter*{1} ??? that is marking up an unnumbered chapter with a title that happens to be the number 1

@DavidCarlisle Yes, I only want a number, not a title.

yes but you are telling latex that you only want a title not a number.  \chapter is a numbered chapter, \chapter* is an unnumbered one,

apart from the markup looking weird and forcing you to number by hand, it will make all the titelsec declarations refer to the wrong part of the heading eg chaptertitlename is supposed to be the name (title) of a chapter not its number, but your "title" is 1.  \chapter{} would be the standard markup for a numbered chapter with an empty title

I'd use \chapter, not \chapter*.
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe} % just for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\large\filcenter}
  {\smash{\thechapter}}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{*2}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\lipsum

\end{document}


With
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*4}{*3}

you'd get

Play at will with the spacings.
